# Is a clustered index faster than a non-clustered index with includes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with columns a,b,c,d,e,f,g that has roughly 500,000 rows.

There is a query that gets run very often that does a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = @a AND b = @b AND c = @c`.

Is it better to create a `clustered index` on a, b, and c, *OR* am I better off creating a `non-clustered index` on a, b, and c `INCLUDE (d, e, f, g)`.

Not sure the include would help speed up the query since the select * was issued.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you do some profiling for both with your actual data?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A clustered index would be the *fastest* for that `SELECT`, but it may not necessarily be *correct* choice.

A clustered index determines the order in which records are physically stored (which is why you can only have one per table).  So while it would be the fastest for THAT query, it may slow down other queries and could KILL updates and inserts if one of those columns was changing, which could mean that the record would need to be physically re-located.

An INCLUDE would also speed up that query at the expense of extra storage and extra index maintenance if any of those fields (including the included fields) were updated.

I would START with a non-clustered index on a, b, and c and see if that gets your performance to a reasonable level.  Anything more could just be trading speed in one area for slowness in another.

Answer (score 2):

The clustered index will be faster.

With `SELECT *`, both your clustered and non-clustered (with include-all) contain all the columns within each page.  However, the non-clustered index ALSO contains a reference back to the clustered key - this is required in case you add more columns to the table, but really also because all indexes (except indexed views) are pointers to the data pages.  The NCI will not feature the new columns (fixed *include* list) but the data pages will.

SQL Server *may* be smart enough to find out that `SELECT *` can be fulfilled by an INDEX SCAN on the NCI (+includes) without a bookmark lookup back to the data pages, but even then, that index scan will be one column wider than the equivalent clustered index scan.

It is normally not a good idea to have a 3-column clustering key.  You may consider an alternative of using a simple single-column identity clustering key, and creating an indexed view clustered around the 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks @RichardTheKiwi, this helps a lot, wasn't 100% sure how it worked under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question as stated in your subject line in general is no.  Because you generally would much prefer to have the narrowest covering (probably non-clustered) index.

But in your case you are selecting * so if the clustered index is good enough match to your seek criteria it's always going to be picked, since anything narrower will need to do a bookmark lookup.

So this raises a big question of why this query is the way it is, whether there is a better choice of clustered index in general for your app (narrow, static, increasing, unique), and whether you really need to be getting all the columns.  Because neither of the two options you give is really that typical of a good design.

500000 rows is fairly small, but if performance is an issue, you want to see how many rows are fitting per page and whether you could improve that be being more selective in your query and having a covering non-clustered index.

Comment: Thanks @Cade, good points.  I don't have any flexibility with the query unfortunately, it's an old ORM that basically does a select * for any table it associates with it's internal entities.  I'll be going with the non-clustered.

Comment: @MarkKadlec You will need to follow up by looking in the profiler or at the query plans in the cache, because it may be highly unlikely that the nonclustered index will even be picked (depending on the existing clustered index) - in which case the nonclustered index will be a complete waste of both space and processing time (because every change to any columns in any row will also require the NCI to be updated since you have all columns in either the key or the non-key included columns).

Answer (score -3):

Your Clustered index is the order the data is stored in the table, so you can only have one clustered index per table.  If you create a new index (non-clustered by default) sure the columns are defined in the index in the same order they are used in the WHERE clause that will allow SQL do a direct index scan to find the record(s) you're looking for.

Comment: So, wich option would be better? (since that's what's being asked)

Comment: Clustered is better, however you want your clustered index to be the uniquest (is that a word?) index on the table, and with several columns contained in the Cluster you need to think about how often you're going to be inserting into the table.  If you're inserting data that would be between values already contained in the tables you are going to cause a lot of page splits and index fragmentation.  Ideally the Value(s) used in your clusted index also shouldn't change.